# Problems with ascii decode in my python interpreter

Tags: python, interpreter, non-ascii-characters

I am testing some models between other things in my python 2.7.6 interpreter cia bpython package installed with pip.

In addition I am using a virtualenv created previously.

When I try type a doblequoes ("") or even slash ("/") character, I get the following message:

UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0x8e in position 1: ordinal not in range(128)

```
>>> coll=sess.collections.create("")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/bgarcial/.virtualenvs/iRODS/bin/bpython", line 11, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/home/bgarcial/.virtualenvs/iRODS/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/bpython/curtsies.py", line 79, in main
    interactive=(not exec_args))
  File "/home/bgarcial/.virtualenvs/iRODS/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/bpython/curtsies.py", line 177, in mainloop
    process_event(e)
  File "/home/bgarcial/.virtualenvs/iRODS/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/bpython/curtsies.py", line 135, in process_event
    repl.process_event(e)
  File "/home/bgarcial/.virtualenvs/iRODS/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/bpython/curtsiesfrontend/repl.py", line 488, in process_event
    return self.process_key_event(e)
  File "/home/bgarcial/.virtualenvs/iRODS/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/bpython/curtsiesfrontend/repl.py", line 629, in process_key_event
    self.add_normal_character(e)
  File "/home/bgarcial/.virtualenvs/iRODS/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/bpython/curtsiesfrontend/repl.py", line 848, in add_normal_character
    self.cursor_offset += 1
  File "/home/bgarcial/.virtualenvs/iRODS/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/bpython/curtsiesfrontend/repl.py", line 1345, in _set_cursor_offset
    self.update_completion()
  File "/home/bgarcial/.virtualenvs/iRODS/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/bpython/curtsiesfrontend/repl.py", line 878, in update_completion
    self.list_win_visible = BpythonRepl.complete(self, tab)
  File "/home/bgarcial/.virtualenvs/iRODS/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/bpython/repl.py", line 599, in complete
    history=self.history)
  File "/home/bgarcial/.virtualenvs/iRODS/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/bpython/autocomplete.py", line 466, in get_completer_bpython
    return get_completer(BPYTHON_COMPLETER, cursor_offset, line, **kwargs)
  File "/home/bgarcial/.virtualenvs/iRODS/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/bpython/autocomplete.py", line 446, in get_completer
    cursor_offset, line, **kwargs)
  File "/home/bgarcial/.virtualenvs/iRODS/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/bpython/autocomplete.py", line 174, in matches
    for filename in self.safe_glob(os.path.expanduser(text)):
  File "/home/bgarcial/.virtualenvs/iRODS/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/bpython/autocomplete.py", line 161, in safe_glob
    return glob.glob(pathname + '*')
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/glob.py", line 27, in glob
    return list(iglob(pathname))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/glob.py", line 60, in iglob
    yield os.path.join(dirname, name)
  File "/home/bgarcial/.virtualenvs/iRODS/lib/python2.7/posixpath.py", line 78, in join
    path +=  b
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0x8e in position 1: ordinal not in range(128)
(iRODS)➜  ~
```

In my python interpreter I can see the UTF-8 encoding

```
(iRODS)➜  ~  python 
Python 2.7.6 (default, Mar 22 2014, 22:59:56) 
[GCC 4.8.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import sys
>>> print sys.stdout.encoding
UTF-8
>>>
```

But, when I use bpython or IPython (installed with pip) , is here when I get the error

```
(iRODS)➜  ~  bpython
bpython version 0.14.1 on top of Python 2.7.6 /home/bgarcial/.virtualenvs/iRODS/bin/python
>>> import sys
>>> print sys.stdout.encoding
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'FakeOutput' object has no attribute 'encoding'
>>>
```

In IPython (and IPython 2) works

```
(iRODS)➜  ~  ipython 
WARNING: Attempting to work in a virtualenv. If you encounter problems, please install IPython inside the virtualenv.
Python 2.7.6 (default, Mar 22 2014, 22:59:56) 
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

IPython 2.4.0 -- An enhanced Interactive Python.
?         -> Introduction and overview of IPython's features.
%quickref -> Quick reference.
help      -> Python's own help system.
object?   -> Details about 'object', use 'object??' for extra details.

In [1]: import sys

In [2]: print sys.stdout.encoding
UTF-8

In [3]:
```

But, the error of encoding denoted previously appear with python, bpython and IPython

I have a problem with some of my interpreter or unless with aome of these utilities associated to it?

As additional information, I am working in my interpreter an API that I installed with pip.

Is possible that there is some problem with these API in relation with Unicode support?

The API is named python-irodsclient (https://github.com/irods/python-irodsclient) and when I ask to developers that create it, they entered an issue in relation with my problem (https://github.com/irods/python-irodsclient/issues/22)

What situation may be happening?
Of anyway I did want share this information here.
Thanks